# Layer File data source

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, layers

I have saved group of layers which are reading from SDE DB as layer file. When I open the layer file in any other MXD it takes the same SDE data source. 
How can I make the layer file without a data source?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. You can change the data source of a layer so that refers to *another* featureclass, but there is no way to clear this information.

Could you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve? I don't see the point of having a layer without a data source.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the answer to your question, I am a little vague as to what you are exactly asking, but if you have a feature class that is being read from an SDE and you wish to make a local copy of that feature class, I would use the Feature Class to Feature Class tool -

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/conversion_tools/feature_class_to_feature_class_conversion_.htm

Using this tool you can make a local copy of the feature class in your own GDB, which is what I think you are asking about, correct me though if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in just viewing the symbology from that layer, but applied to a different data source?

In that case, you will want to [import symbology from another layer](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000087000000).